# Breakage when editing code segment in comment?

Tags: bug

Sometimes I put a short bit of code in a comment, maybe as a suggestion for improvement to question or answer.

Sometimes I get it wrong first time, and hit edit to get it right.

This used to work and preserved the markdown. But right now it creates a bit of a mess. It loses markdown, spaces and underscores, plus it duplicates code segments inside backtick markers. This just had me scrambling to correct my comment inside the 5 minute window . . .

Is this a bug, or is a there a new better way of having code segment markdown in comments?

If relevant, browser is Chrome, on a Mac OS X.

---

Replication steps (done as a comment on this question):

1. Click "Add a comment" on any question or answer

[image: Step 1]

2. Save the comment. So far, so good.

[image: Step 2]

3. Click "edit" on the comment inside 5 minute window:

[image: Step 3]

4. Save the edit (which shows it is not just the text box having this problem)

[image: Step 4]

Comment: Example original comment: `var_a + var_b`

Comment: Example comment edited: vara+varbvara+varbvar_a + var_b

Comment: Testing, `testing, testing`...

Comment: I didn't repro above. Are underscores required for this problem?

Comment: Without underscores: test∈g,test∈gtest∈g,test∈gtesting, testing

Comment: Maybe some browser specific thing then? No issue on IPad Safari.

Comment: @MartinSmith: No, in fact as you see I got even weirder result doing same as you. I see the fault as soon as I hit edit, and in the garbled version above just saving as-is. What is then saved matches exactly what I see in the edit text box.

Comment: 'If relevant, browser is Chrome' - what a surprise.  Next...  :)

Comment: Could you edit the question with the exact steps? I can't reproduce this either. Possibly with screenshots and red-circles :p

Comment: @Neil, does this persist across page reloads / browser sessions? Does it survive safe mode?

Comment: Example for screenshot: a=b+ca=b+ca = b + c

Comment: Without MathJax for Chrome plugin: a=b+ca=b+ca = b + c. Nope not that (only plugin I added recently)

Comment: Have any of the people voting "cannot reproduce" actually tested it on Chrome on a Mac?

Comment: Without Markdown Preview plugin (a likely-sounding possibility): a=b+ca=b+ca = b +c. Nope not that.

Comment: New session (signed in Incognito mode): `a + b = c` - aha that works OK. Looks like it is something in the session, @FrédéricHamidi thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Incognito disables all addins AFAIK so I assume the issue is caused by one of those.

Comment: Incognito with MathJax enabled: a=b+ca=b+ca = b + c

Comment: @MartinSmith: I think that's a direct hit. I enabled MathJax plugin, and it looks likely that is the culprit. Although disabling the plugin didn't seem to clear the fault earlier . . .

Answer (score 3):

From suggestions in comments, and experiments with Incognito mode plus enabling the few plugins I have, it looks like this fault is triggered by Chrome's MathJax plugin.

It seems that this plugin and editing markdown with back-ticks in HTML text box are not compatible.

I enabled MathJax for Kaggle, not Stack Overflow, and it's only for convenience on a few of the former's pages. So I will just remove the plugin. From my experience it seems it may need to be completely removed, not just disabled.

If anyone else experiences something similar, then I hope this will help. If you *must* have the MathJax plugin, then I am not sure what the options are.